# How can I upload the files on Github to AWS S3 bucket using boto3?

Tags: python, github, amazon-s3, boto3, github-actions

I am automating a task using boto3. I have configured the S3 bucket to host a static website, I want to upload my HTML files from github to s3 bucket using boto3. Is that possible?
I was thinking of using pyGithub to clone the repo locally and the upload it to AWS s3 using boto3.
Any other way I can achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern describes the steps required to add a continuous integration and continuous delivery (CI/CD) pipeline to s3 bucket .
It uses GitHub as a source provider. The pipeline gets triggered when new items are committed, and the changes are then reflected in the S3 bucket.[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. which would be a better option? Using github actions or AWS codepipeline? I assume aws would cost more?

Comment: Using github action  require AWS credentials with s3 write permissions which can be a security challeng.

Comment: Yes thats something to think about. In my case I am doing all this using python so aws has an api and actions api are still in beta. I guess it leaves me with aws codepipeline.
Thanks!